# Block access to kibana from default port

Tags: security, nginx, elasticsearch, kibana

I have Kibana running in a remote server, I want to secure it's interface.
First I installed an Nginx proxy server secured by a user and password on top of it, so I can access Kibana interface using this secured server...
But, I still be able to access Kibana on the default port 5601 which is not secured...
How can disable kibana access from 5601 and still have it on my secured proxy server.
I tried  `server.host: "127.0.0.1"` configuration option, but it didn't work

Comment: You can redirect Kibana to another port (e.g. 443) and secured it with nginx. Then, you can disable 5601 port from all the external IPs. However, securing with X-Pack is a much more neat solution that does not need any kind of hacking [link](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/x-pack)

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict which IP address is allowed to connect to your Kibana instance in kibana.yml. Look for the server.host parameter.

If you put the IP of your nginx server IP in this value, only the nginx server will be permitted to connect.